# Embed Python script

Tags: .net, python, vb.net, visual-studio, deployment

I have some Python Scripts which I would like to use from my VB.NET class library however instead of increasing the amount of files that I distribute is it possible to embed the script into my project/dll in Visual Studio and then run the script from the dll during my program runtime?

Thanks for any help.

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, it is possible](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be [looking for this](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_embedded_resources.html), but I am not sure.  This is possible, however.

The link above shows you how to add the file/script as an embedded resource.  If that isn't what you are after, [vartec's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686690/embed-python-script/686705#686705) describes how to embed the python runtime directly.